# Django/python: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-generic-views

I am trying to create a list_view for a model queryset. When running my server, it returns : attribute error - 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'. I would appreciate helping me in solve this.

Here's my code:

Views.py:

```
@login_required 
class live_bids(ListView):

    model = Post 
    template_name = 'loggedin_load/live_bids.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('bids').filter(user=self.request.user)
```

urls.py:

```
 url(r'^live_bids/$', live_bids.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't use the `login_required` decorator on a class like that. You need to use `method_decorator`. On Django 1.9+, you can decorate the class:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class LiveBids(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    ...
```

On earlier versions, you need to override `dispatch` and use `method_decorator` there.

```
class LiveBids(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LiveBids, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The easiest solution is to use [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) instead of the decorator (works with Django 1.9+)

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class LiveBids(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post 
    template_name = 'loggedin_load/live_bids.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('bids').filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Note that in the examples, I have renamed the view to `LiveBids`, to match the recommended Django style. You'll have to update the url pattern as well.

Comment: is there a way to do it for flask?

Comment: @JohnSmith this question has nothing to do with flask. Please ask a new question.

Comment: [done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932366/how-to-use-login-required-with-a-class-in-flask)

Comment: this was very useful! Thanks @Alasdair