# How to use login_required with a class, in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

```
from flask_login import login_required
from flask_restful import Resource

@login required
class MyClass(Resource):
    #...
```

In the main file I call the class's methods like:

```
api.add_resource(MyClass, '/some_url', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
```

I think I am using `@login_required` the wrong way here, since I get the error
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'`

So I am assuiming that `@login_required` can only be used with functions. Is there a way to incorporate it with a class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could give the `class` the decorators it should run :

```
class MyClass(Resource):
    decorators = [login_required]
```

Comment: used `method_decorators`, but still the same. Thanks